# Managing/cleaning up multiple caches

Tags: caching, f#

I'm running a complex computation (a [Markov chain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain))

```
let memoize f =
    let cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<'key,'value>()
    cache, fun x -> cache.GetOrAdd(x, Func<'key, 'value>f)
```

to cache intermediate results of multiple functions. The overall structure is something like this

```
module Foo =
    [...]
    let _, foo' = memoize foo

module Bar =
    [...]
    let _, bar' = memoize bar 

module Main = 
    open Foo
    open Bar
    [...]
    let result =
        foobar (foo' a) (bar' b)
```

Typically I run this once and then the program terminates, but it's obviously not nice to not clean up those cache dictionaries. Also, I sometimes need to call the model for many different inputs and then I quickly run into memory issues. What's the best way to clean up multiple caches at once?

**Edit**

A mentioned in the comments, it would of course be possible to collect all caches into a list. But I'd have to box the dictionaries and it doesn't seem nice to me. Is there a better (overall) strategy?

Comment: What about putting them in a list and then calling `caches |> Seq.iter (fun c -> c.Clear())`?

Comment: Sure. That would certainly possible. Somehow it didn't seem very nice to me... you'd have to box it etc. But maybe I'm overthinking this...

Comment: No  need to box them, you cold just store the `Clear` functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a more robust caching structure than `ConcurrentDictionary` so that you can specify an expiration policy.  [Here's one on FSSnip](http://fssnip.net/7UT) that wraps `ConcurrentDictionary` and allow for time-based expiration, but you could add expiration based on other criteria.  This would allow you to just use `memoizeWithExpiration` without having to worry about clean-up on the calling side.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my suggestion, simple and effective:

```
module Foo =
    [...]
    let fcache, foo' = memoize foo

module Bar =
    [...]
    let bcache, bar' = memoize bar

module Main = 
    open Foo
    open Bar
    let clearCaches = [
        fcache.Clear
        bcache.Clear
    ]
    [...]
    let result =
        foobar (foo' a) (bar' b)
    let clearAll() =
        clearCaches  |> Seq.iter (fun clear -> clear())
```

**Update**

If you wanted to collect the `clear` functions automatically the memoize function could do it, like this:

```
let clearCaches = Dictionary<_,_>()

let memoize (name:string) f =
    let cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<'key,'value>()
    clearCaches.Add(name, cache.Clear)
    fun x -> cache.GetOrAdd(x, Func<'key, 'value>f)

module Foo =
    [...]
    let foo' = memoize "Foo.foo" foo

module Bar =
    [...]
    let bar' = memoize "Bar.bar" bar

module Main = 
    open Foo
    open Bar
    [...]
    let result =
        foobar (foo' a) (bar' b)

    let clearAll() =
        clearCaches  |> Seq.iter (fun kvp -> kvp.Value())
```

Which would also allow you to clear them individually or using certain conditions, like by module, etc.

Comment: Right, didn't think about that. Nice and simple! But of course not so convenient if you have a lot of different function calls, and maybe work with a parallel lop over `foobar`